# Float element that fit whole height

Tags: html, css

I need to create something like this:

[image]

And I created this html

```
<li>
  <strong>Version 2.0</strong>
  <span>Text</span> -
  <i>December 29, 2013</i>
</li>
```

But I can't make version to fit the whole height when it have float, I need to have float because version can have different size.

I've try to set `height: 100%`, `position: relative` and `margin-bottom: auto` also `top:0; bottom: 0` but it only work with `position: absolute` but then it don't float.

Anybody know how can I make my html to be like on the screen?

Comment: Is the HTML structure locked or could you amend it?

Comment: @Paulie_D you can change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your date inside your text container, because that will presumably always immediately follow your text.

You could display your elements as blocks and float your header to the left. If you then give your text `overflow:hidden` property, it will clear the floated element and take up any remaining space:

The `margin` and `list-style-type` are to look prettier

```
li{list-style-type:none}
li strong{display:block; float:left; margin-right:5px;}
li span{display:block; overflow:hidden;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9f3uLb2f/)

Another way would be to display your list item as a `table`, and it's children elements as `table-cells`. You'd probably want to set a `width` for your `strong` element if you were going to choose this way:

```
li{display:table;}
li strong{display:table-cell; width:100px;}
li span{display:table-cell}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9f3uLb2f/1/)

Comment: `display: block` with `overflow: hidden` work perfect.

Comment: @jcubic Glad to have helped :)